# Uso de setters no construtor

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, construtor, getters-setters

Eu gostaria de saber se há alguma diferença, semanticamente falando, entre esses dois construtores:

```
public Aluno(String n, float n1, float n2) {
   this.nome = n;
   this.setNota1(n1);
   this.setNota2(n2);
}
```

e

```
public Aluno(String n, float n1, float n2) {
   this.nome = n;
   this.nota = n1;
   this.nota2 = n2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com isto:

```
this.nota = n1;
this.nota2 = n2;
```

Você esta acessando as variaveis diretamente. Já estes dois são métodos que podem fazer qualquer coisa:

```
this.setNota1(n1);
this.setNota2(n2);
```

No caso se `setNota1` for assim:

```
public setNota1(float n1) {
   this.nota = n1;
}
```

Então acho que é redundante criar um método apenas pra setar uma variavel, melhor ficar com o primeiro mesmo:

```
public Aluno(String n, float n1, float n2) {
   this.nome = n;
   this.nota = n1;
   this.nota2 = n2;
}
```

No caso você só vai usar o `setNota1` e `setNota2` quando quiser alterar apenas as notas, isto eu quero dizer fora do método, assim:

```
Foo test = new Aluno("João", 6, 6.5);

//Aqui se a condição for true ele irá mudar apenas a nota1:
if (minha condição) {
    test.setNota1(8);
}
```

Recomendo que leia:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/package.html

Answer (score 5):

Não sei exatamente o que você quis dizer com *semântica*, mas podemos ver a questão de várias perspectivas.

## Clareza

Usar métodos *setter* pode ser mais confuso pois se outra pessoa vai ler o seu código.

Ela pode assumir incorretamente que o método *setter* executa ou não alguma lógica dentro dele, então ela precisa navegar para os métodos e olhar o que eles fazem.

Observe nas outras respostas que elas sempre acabam inferindo algo ou colocando uma condição. Imagine um sistema com vários casos desse e você pode extrapolar quanta complexidade isso vai adicionar à vida de todos.

Sempre use a solução mais simples. Neste caso, sempre use a atribuição direta quando possível.

Eu imagino que isso pode parecer "feio" para alguns, principalmente porque quando começamos a usar orientação a objetos, ficamos com a impressão que qualquer manipulação direta de atributos de alguma forma quebra o encapsulamento.

Mas o escopo da classe é de propriedade dela mesma. Uma classe não precisa de segredos para si mesma, ou começamos a enveredar para a insanidade. Poderíamos dizer que uma classe que encapsula a si mesma tem múltiplas personalidades?

## Efeito

Imaginando agora que os *setters* apenas atribuem, o efeito final seria o mesmo da atribuição. Porém, isso não é sempre tão simples, principalmente onde há concorrência envolvida.

Entenda concorrência como o ato de acessar e modificar um mesmo atributo ou objeto a partir de diferentes *threads* ao mesmo tempo.

Em cenários concorrentes, você sempre deve usar os modificadores `final` ou `volatile`, pois eles garantem que o estado das variáveis vai ser escrito na memória principal e todas as *threads* vão enxergar o valor correto. Caso contrário uma *thread* pode ler o valor antigo em cache.

Uma forma eficiente de compartilhar objetos entre *threads* é usando objetos imutáveis. Nesse caso, é recomendável usar `final` em todos os atributos. Exemplo:

```
private final String nome;
private final float n1;
```

No exemplo acima, os atributos `final` somente podem ser atribuídos uma única vez e isso deve ocorrer até o fim da execução do construtor. Atributos `final` não podem ter a atribuição delegada a um *setter*.

## Manutenção e evitando erros bobos

Além de atributos, podemos também declarar os parâmetros como `final`, isto é, que não podem ter o valor alterado. Exemplo:

```
public Aluno(final String n, final float n1, final float n2) {...}
```

No que isso ajuda?

Primeiro, você evita erros bobos como:

```
public Aluno(String nome, float nota1, float nota2) {
   this.nome = nome;
   this.nota1 = nota1;
   nota2 = nota2;
}
```

Acredite, já corrigi *errinhos bobos* como este acima em produção muitas vezes. Isso seria evitado se os parâmetros fosse `final`:

```
public Aluno(final String nome, final float nota1, final float nota2) {
   this.nome = nome;
   this.nota1 = nota1;
   nota2 = nota2; //erro de compilação aqui
}
```

Isso também ajuda a lembrar que não se deve modificar parâmetros de métodos para reusá-lo como uma variável, como se isso fosse economizar memória ou algo do tipo.

## Executando lógica

Se existe a necessidade de executar alguma lógica no método *setter*, sugiro uma alternativa:

```
public Aluno(String nome, float nota1, float nota2) {
   this.nome = nome;
   this.nota1 = verificarNotaValida(nota1);
   this.nota2 = verificarNotaValida(nota2);
}

public void setNota1(float nota1) {
    this.nota1 = verificarNotaValida(nota1);
}
```

Extrair a lógica de validação permite maior reúso e deixa o código claro.

Answer (score 2):

Depende do que os métodos `setNota1()` e `setNota2()` fazem. Se eles só atribuem o valor do parâmetro para `nota` e `nota2` então não há diferença alguma. Obviamente que se os métodos fazem qualquer coisa diferente, mínima que seja, então há diferença.

Answer (score 1):

Não porque os atributos são todos da mesma classe. A não ser que os métodos set façam mais alguma coisa além de atribuir valor ao atributo.