# Devo criar construtor com Setter? PHP

Tags: php, getters-setters

Qual melhor e mais seguro método de criar o construtor?

O Netbeans cria direto alterando a variável, mas tem como usar o setter. Então, qual melhor e mais seguro método? Por exemplo:

**Sem setter**

```
function __construct($nome, $idade, $sexo) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->idade = $idade;
        $this->sexo = $sexo;
    }
```

**Com setter**

```
function __construct($nome, $idade, $sexo) {
        $this->setNome($nome);
        $this->setIdade($idade);
        $this->setSexo($sexo);
    }
```

Comment: A única diferença é que no segundo caso vai chamar o método `set` ao invés de colocar o valor direto. Não tem melhor, não tem mais seguro.

Comment: Mas em questão de segurança não muda nada?

Comment: Não. Encapsulamento nada tem a ver com segurança.

Comment: A diferença é as regras de negócio que você pode (ou não) ter implementado no setter. Se você define a associação direta, você está pulando uma etapa. Mas de restante não vejo problema.

Comment: Duplicada de onde, pode passar o link, LINQ? kkkkkkk ficou estranho perguntar isso. Link LINQ

Comment: O link tá lá em cima, é só ler a aquela caixa amarela. Aliás, eu não marquei a pergunta como dup, marquei como fora de escopo. O sistema sempre vai no voto decisivo.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95881/uso-de-setters-no-construtor

Comment: Obrigado LINQ e os demais!

Comment: Sim. Se houver tratamento da informação, você perderia o benefício do encapsulamento na sua própria classe.